# Gatsby app running on a Docker container can't send data to the browser

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gatsby

I need help diagnosing and fixing an issue with running gatsby on a Docker container. I've installed gatsby and created a project as per documentation. I think ran `npm install` followed by `npm run develop`. The default app was able to render on my browser successfully. I went on to create a Dockerfile inside the project's directory, built a container and run it. All were successful. However, when I go to where I believe the app is served i.e. `localhost:8000`, I get the error that:

```
*This page isn’t working*
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Here are files I think are relevant:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:20.5-alpine3.17 as builder
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm cache clean --force && npm ci --omit=dev
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "run", "develop" ]
EXPOSE 8000
```

**Script to build and run the container**

```
#!/bin/bash
docker build -t frontend-img:1.0.0-dev .
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Docker image built successfully."
  docker run -it --rm --name frontend-container -p 8000:8000 frontend-img:1.0.0-dev
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Docker container is now running on port 8000."
  else
    echo "Error: Failed to start Docker container."
  fi
else
  echo "Error: Docker image build failed. Container not started."
fi
```

First, I checked container logs, thinking maybe I'll get an error, but the command `docker logs frontend-container`  returned the same output as running `npm run develop` which shows a successful build.

I then ran `docker ps` to check the status of my container and found it to be working fine(Up 2 minutes). So I ran `curl http://localhost:8000` which gave me the output:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8000
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Meaning the connection was successful, but the server did not provide a response. This being the case, I went into the container to check if indeed the app is running from there. So I did the following:

**Checking that Gatsby is running**

```
$ docker exec -it frontend-container /bin/sh
/frontend # ps aux | grep node
   23 root      0:04 node /frontend/node_modules/.bin/gatsby develop
   39 root      1:15 /usr/local/bin/node /frontend/.cache/tmp-23-ya81gSYB4yyC
  107 root      0:07 /usr/local/bin/node /frontend/node_modules/gatsby-worker/dist/child.js
  168 root      0:00 grep node
```

The first command tells me there's a node process running `gatsby develop`, meaning it's running. So I continued:

```
/frontend # wget http://localhost:8000
Connecting to localhost:8000 (127.0.0.1:8000)
saving to 'index.html'
index.html           100% |************************************************************************************************|  2849  0:00:00 ETA
'index.html' saved
```

Meaning everything is well, in the container.